# how to inject a delegate in swift using typhoon?

Tags: ios, swift, typhoon

Using typhoon I'm trying to inject the type of "worker" in my view controller. my "Worker" requires a delegate so that when the work is done, it calls this method. I need to set my view controller to be the delegate of the worker class that was injected. in other words a circular dependency.

### Updated question with source:

```
//my typhoon assembly class
import Typhoon
class Assembly : TyphoonAssembly {

    public dynamic func viewController() -> AnyObject {
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(ViewController.self) {
            (definition) in

            definition.injectProperty("worker", with: self.foo())
            definition.scope = TyphoonScope.Singleton
        }
    }


    public dynamic func foo() -> AnyObject {
        return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(Foo.self) {
            (definition) in

            definition.injectProperty("delegate", with: self.viewController())
        }
    }

}
```

`Foo` is where the work done, it implements `WorkHandler` protocol and has a delegate of type `SomeProtocol` to call when work has finished:

```
import Foundation

@objc
protocol SomeProtocol: class {
    optional func hasFinishedWork(value: Bool)
}

protocol WorkHandler : class {
    func doSomething()
}



class Foo: WorkHandler{

    //how will this get set?
    var delegate:SomeProtocol?

    func doSomething(){
        print("doing the work")
        delegate?.hasFinishedWork!(true)
    }
}
```

And my ViewController conforms to SomeProtocol like so:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, SomeProtocol{

    var worker:WorkHandler?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        worker?.doSomething();
    }

    @objc func hasFinishedWork(value: Bool){
        print("The work was all done")
    }
}
```

above code gives the following error when it runs:

`2016-02-29 20:25:43.250 TestApp[30604:5316415] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Subclass of NSProxy or NSObject is required.'`

Is anyone able to help with this?

Comment: Swift is the same as Objective-C: https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Types%20of%20Injections#circular-dependencies  . . it works because of Typhoon's ObjectGraph scope (default).

Comment: @JasperBlues any example code you know of in swift? Seems like i do indeed need to use the circular dependency injection but couldn't make it work. Their example project PocketForcast didn't help.

Comment: swift has a powerful enum it delights me how easily it can solve the complicated problems.

Comment: Your code sample is missing the defition of the `foo()` method, which should return an instance of `Foo`.  That's where you'd `injectProperty(@selector(delegate), with:self.appSettingsController)`.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson no that's not it. I've added the full source above. please have a look. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i had to make my protocol to inherit from NSObject:

```
@objc
protocol SomeProtocol: class {
    optional func hasFinishedWork(value: Bool)
}

@objc
protocol WorkHandler : class {
    func doSomething()
}




class Foo: NSObject, WorkHandler{

    //how will this get set?
    var delegate:SomeProtocol?

    @objc func doSomething(){
        print("doing the work")
        delegate?.hasFinishedWork!(true)
    }
}
```

Now it works as expected.